# How to erase any kind of files after formating and installing Fedora 27 Workstation

Tags: linux, fedora, secure-erase, wipe

How can I safely erase files that could potentially be recovered after a hard drive format and installation on a Fedora 27 workstation? I was using Windows 10, and everything that I had in Windows 10 I don't want to be recoverable. I'm going to sell this device, so I need a way to do this without damaging my current OS. Please be specific about what commands I need to use.

my DF details are :

```
devtmpfs                  1943380        0   1943380   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1956768    22416   1934352   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     1956768     1632   1955136   1% /run
tmpfs                     1956768        0   1956768   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  51343840  9373768  39332248  20% /
tmpfs                     1956768      100   1956668   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                  999320   211228    719280  23% /boot
/dev/sda1                  204580    17420    187160   9% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/fedora-home 422840936 24134360 377157728   7% /home
tmpfs                      391352       16    391336   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                      391352       68    391284   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                      391352        0    391352   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Did you choose encryption when you installed the system?

Comment: Yeah, i did. :c

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner (the tools also exist on Fedora). Unless you are being watched by your government, don't overdo it... OTOH the price of 2nd hand 500GB HDDs is low, you can also just break it (drill a hole in it).

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypted your disk when installing Fedora (and from the comments, it looks like you did), and the passphrase isn't "password" or something like that, you don't need to do anything else. This is one of the huge advantages of using full-disk encryption. When you're done, send it in to be recycled with no further worry.

Comment: You can use `cryptsetup luksKillSlot` to remove passwords, even the remaining last one, after which there is practically no way to recover the disk.

Comment: Yeah the passphrase isnt password is about 18 char.. the complexity is 9/10, so am i safe if i encrypt when i was installing? if the "buyer" use tool to search for files, etc?

Comment: Yeah; without the passphrase, it's as good as random noise.